# javascript window.location do I need to escape?

Tags: javascript

```
    var delivery_date = $("#year").val()+'-'+$("#month").val()+'-'+$('#day').val();
    var delivery_time = $("#delivery_time").val();
    var zone = $("#zone").val();
    window.location = window.location+'/'+delivery_date + '/'+ delivery_time + '/'+ zone;
```

Do I need to escape the parameters in window.location = window.location...etc

zone could be something with spaces, quotes,..etc

Comment: Do you have URL mapping, or did you mean to send those values as query string data to the same page?

Comment: if you want encode url use `encodeURIComponent()` instead of `escaspe()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to properly url-encode the parameters. See [here](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/escape.htm) for more information; [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to have the php url_encode and url_decode behaviour use:

```
function url_encode(str) {
    str = (str + '').toString();
    return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/!/g, '%21').replace(/'/g, '%27').replace(/\(/g, '%28'). replace(/\)/g, '%29').replace(/\*/g, '%2A').replace(/%20/g, '+');
}

function url_decode(str) {
    return decodeURIComponent((str + '').replace(/\+/g, '%20'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

```
var zone = encodeURIComponent($("#zone").val());
```