# encodeURIComponent is failing

Tags: javascript, jquery, .htaccess, urlencode, url-encoding

So I am trying to create a search in my website and I need to encode some text so it is URL friendly. However, if I search anything with a "<" symbol I get HTTP error 403 (access forbidden) because the "<" is not being encoded.

This is the code I am using:

```
var search = $("#txtHomeSearch").val();

if(search != ""){
    var urlSearch = encodeURIComponent(search);
    window.location.href = "/search&s=" + urlSearch;
}
```

Example of a working url: **http://website.com/search&s=helloword**
Example of a broken url : **http://website.com/search&s=<**

Maybe the problem is with my .htaccess file which contains:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^.*]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
ErrorDocument 404 /errorPages/404.php
```

Comment: `<` is not a special character in URLs, so it doesn't require encoding.

Comment: When a "<" is in my url I get HTTP error 403, that is why I need to encode it

Comment: What server are you using?

Comment: This kind of sounds like asp.net request validation, but I'd think you'd be getting a 500 error, not a 403.

Comment: Xampp apache. I have a create a root htaccess, which may be causing the problem.
RewriteRule ^([^.*]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]

Comment: @JamesConnor Is it normal that `/search&s=` isnt `/search?s=`?

Comment: @plalx yes, I have modified the url in htaccess. The "real" url is http://website.com/index.php?page=search&s=<

Comment: Perhaps you could temporary hack it using `&lt;` and decoding on the other end until you find the real issue. Actually `<` gets encoded to `%3C` for me with `encodeURIComponent('<');`

Comment: If I use document.write() I get %3C but I it does not get encoded when I use window.location.href

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple utility here: http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/escape for verifying the operation of the various Javascript escaping functions. Accoring to the ECMA standard, and verified using that tool, the "<" should be escaped correctly by the encodeURIComponent() function.

Could it be a character other than "<" causing the problem? There are various remedies for the characters that encodeURIComponent misses.  One is the url_encode function listed here and elsewhere: [javascript window.location do I need to escape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486513/javascript-window-location-do-i-need-to-escape)

Comment: No other character is causing the problem. This works... "http://localhost/search&s=helloworld" and this does not work "http://localhost/search&s=<"

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping your back reference using `[B]` flag.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^.*]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [B,L]
ErrorDocument 404 /errorPages/404.php
```